# Count number of times 2 words appear in cells

Tags: vlookup, countif

can someone help me. I am looking to count how many times 2 words appear in a column full of job titles. For example I want to know how many Programme Managers there are in column D. Job titles in column D include EDI Programme Manager, Change Programme Manager, Programme Delivery Manager, National Programme Development Manager. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretical answer:

Use `UNIQUE()` [1] to create a list of present job titles - assuming you have ONE in each cell.
Then based on that list, use `COUNTIF()` [2] to actually count them

**Also possible, a bit more manual, older Excel-versions:**
Create an Autofilter on the data,
insert a row ABOVE the data and type in `=SUBTOTAL(103,A:A)-1` [3] in e.g. B1  (i.e. not in column A).
Then filter on the unique job-titles in the correct column and you will see how many lines you have visible (= also after setting the filter).

Ref:
[1] https://www.google.com/search?q=unique+excel
[2] https://www.google.com/search?q=countif+excel
[3] https://www.google.com/search?q=subtotal+excel